# How to retrieve all certificates in your X509Store

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate

I am using the following code to retrieve all certificates in my PC from an asp.net webapp. The certificates collection is empty, and I can't understand why.

I tried impersonating my own user account and I didn't succeed as well. What am I doing wrong?

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser); //StoreLocation.LocalMachine fails too
var certificates = store.Certificates;
foreach (var certificate in certificates)
{
    var friendlyName = certificate.FriendlyName;
    Console.WriteLine(friendlyName);
}

//original problem: fetch a single certificate by its subject name
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = CertificateUtility.GetCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser,  "CN=mypc.domainname"); //returns null :(
```

Comment: I can make it work locally, when I publish and the client accesses the system, it can not find the certificates. Is there any way to find the certificates on the client, with the application on the server?

Comment: For those coding a UWP app you will need to add the Shared User Certificates capability in the mainifest. Otherwise, you'll get an empty list instead of an exception.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add this line of code to the second line and see how it works:

```
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
```

and then this at the bottom :):

```
store.Close();
```

Comment: I also use this to open the store:  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

Comment: @rickschott: Good point, but since they're bit flags, and the enum value of `OpenFlags.ReadOnly` is 0, specifying it alongside other flags has no specific effect. It will be treated as read-only as long as you don't give the `OpenFlags.ReadWrite` (value 1) flag. `OpenFlags.ReadOnly` is really just a default value to give because the function requires a parameter. Its description isn't even correct technically, since, as I said, it's not a real flag; it doesn't contain a bit to change.

Comment: Or you can just wrap it in a `using` block since `X509Store` implements `IDisposable` ;)

Comment: @RJCuthbertson The `IDisposable` interface is only supported by the `X509Store` class since .NET Framework 4.6. Before that you had to wrap it in a `try-finally` block.

Comment: I can make it work locally, when I publish and the client accesses the system, it can not find the certificates. Is there any way to find the certificates on the client, with the application on the server?

Comment: It is likely that the security context your client is running in does not have permissions to view the certs you're targeting.

Answer (score 22):

All in one ...

I have an apache server (xamp) with https. I access through https and c# (vs2010) 
to a PHP upload page

1. Install the certificate from i.e in the personal folder certificate, for example.
2. To view the certicates run "certmgr.msc" , at least in win7

#### Listing the personal certificates

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser); 

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); 

var certificates = store.Certificates;
foreach (var certificate in certificates)
{
    var friendlyName = certificate.FriendlyName;
    var xname = certificate.GetName(); //obsolete
    Console.WriteLine(friendlyName);
}

store.Close();
```

#### Find specific certificate

```
string certificateName = "CN=localhost"; //name found in the var xname
X509Store storex = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                    storex.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certificatesx =
            storex.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, 
            certificateName,
            true);

X509Certificate certificatex = certificates[0];

storex.Close();
```

Comment: I've made an edit to improve the markup of this post and introduce capitalisation, but the first sentence and point still make limited sense to me. Anyone with a better understanding up for editing?

Comment: I can make it work locally, when I publish and the client accesses the system, it can not find the certificates. Is there any way to find the certificates on the client, with the application on the server?

Answer (score 3):

I can find certificates by ...

```
var certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

var certificateCollection = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "mycert.me.com",false);

certificateStore.Close();

var certificate = certificateCollection[0];
```

certificateCollection will have the certificates I care about ... if it is just one then I get first element in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Look in your certificate store(mmc/add/certificate snap-in/my user account/Certificates - Current User/Personal/Certificates) to see the subject name to make sure "CN=mypc.domainname" is whats actually on the cert.

```
"CN=mypc.domainname"
```

vs

```
"CN = mypc.domainname"
```

...etc

Comment: Yes, I just didn't want to expose my real pc/domain name here. ;)

Comment: I know that's not the real CN name you have, just want you to make sure your "mypc.domainame", whatever it really is, is whats on your cert.