# What should be SetCertificate() arguments for this certificate?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

For this certificate, what should be the arguments of the following call? I tried the following and it did not work.

```
X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
     StoreLocation.LocalMachine
    ,StoreName.CertificateAuthority
    ,X509FindType.FindBySubjectName
    ,"CN=MPCA" // also tried without CN=
);
```

[image]

Comment: are you receiving an error of any kind?

Comment: Also, you may want to tinker with your code and test that the cert is where you expect it and is acessible.  This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729302/how-to-retrieve-all-certificates-in-your-x509store shows how to retrieve all certs from the store.

Comment: The error is kind of obvious: certificate could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Certificate Tool's `TrustedRootCertificateAuthorities` store name maps to `StoreName.Root` in .NET X509 API.

```
X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
     StoreLocation.LocalMachine
    ,StoreName.Root
    ,X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber
    ,"FA###########434" // serial found by enumerating all certs
);
```

Or:

```
X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
     StoreLocation.LocalMachine
    ,StoreName.Root
    ,X509FindType.FindBySubjectName
    ,"MPCA" // Without CN=
);
```